# Can't load text from database inside Tiny MCE Editor

Tags: php, database, tinymce, echo

I'm using the tiny mce editor in my website and I want to load some text from database in the text area that uses tinymce.

The javascript configuration for the editor is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    editor_selector : "mceAdvanced",
    plugins : "style,table,iespell,preview,directionality,inlinepopups",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,link,unlink,image,code,|,forecolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "css/example.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
});
</script>
```

and this is the way I'm trying to load the text inside textarea:

```
<textarea name="program" cols="40" rows="12" class="contact_fields mceAdvanced"><? php echo $row_this_trip['program']; ?></textarea>
```

Also none of the following is working:

```
<textarea name="program" cols="40" rows="12" class="contact_fields mceAdvanced">Lorem Ipsum</textarea>
```

or

```
<textarea name="program" cols="40" rows="12" class="contact_fields mceAdvanced"><?php echo( htmlentities( $row_this_trip['program'] ) ); ?></textarea>
```

I can't find what's wrong in this. Can you please help me?

Comment: I can't Google it right now, but in addition to pre-setting the textarea (which should work) most Rich editors have a specialized JavaScript function to load Data into the editor. You should find that in the Documentation, maybe this helps.

Comment: We use TinyMCE and can just echo content in between the textarea tags,  his code should work.

Comment: Can you confirm that there is actually some output in the textarea?
Do you get any Javascript error messages? 
Can you post the code you initialize the Textarea with?

Comment: I have searched the wiki and documentation of mce but didn't find any solution. That's why I supposed that there must be something wrong with my code. Still can't find out what it is though.

Comment: I am sure that the "echo $row_this_trip['program']" command contains text, cause if I place it anywhere else in my page, the text is visible. But when I place it inside textarea, it's just not working.

Comment: if you view source code of the document, does the text appear there inside the <textarea></textarea> tags?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have link in your html to the TinyMCE script?

```
<script src="linktoscript.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Comment: yes of course, the editor works ok besides the fact that I cannot load text in it. 

I also just found out that the problem is appearing only in firefox browser. Everything works ok, using all other browsers. This is weird.

Answer (score -1):

[tinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/) has a `triggerSave` event.

```
tinymce.triggerSave();
```

For example,

```
tinymce.triggerSave();

$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'autoSaveReport.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
          var redirectURL = window.location.pathname;
          var redirectURL1 = redirectURL+"?incid="+result;
            window.location = window.location+"?incid="+result;
         }
      });
```